# AngularJS - Pass parameter from main to partial template on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass a value to the partial template controller on click from the main view. I am passing the value to the main controller without a problem but I don't know how to pass it to the "test-template.html" controller. The goal is to refresh only the partial view when a $scope in the main view changes. Thank you in advance for the help.

```
<md-list flex>
<md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">Topic 1</md-subheader>
<md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="PassValue(item.ID)">
    <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
        <p>{{ item.ID }}</p>
        <p>{{ item.Name }}</p>
        <h4>{{ item.Description }}</h4>
    </div>
</md-list-item>
</md-content>
<div layout="column" style="min-width: 75%;">
<md-toolbar>
    <h4 class="md-toolbar-tools">Documents: </h4>
</md-toolbar>
<div ng-include src='"../HtmlTemplates/test-template.html"' ng-controller="TestTemplController" onload="hi(item.TopicID)"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that if template is using a different controller.

You can use a service/factory to share the variable among the controller

Comment: Thank you. The goal is to refresh only the partial view when a $scope in the main view changes. Could you give me an idea how can I do that

Comment: you could have a $scope variable and add a watch for it, and change the view accordingly

Comment: Thank you. but the view needs to be  with dynamic data depending on this scope variable. How can I pass the scope variable to the partial view and generate the data for the partial view.

Comment: @user6934713 yes that's the thing, you need to share the variable and load the controller